# Avoid duplicate values in input tag, type text without javascript in Jinja2

Tags: html, google-app-engine, jinja2

So let's say a user is signing up, and I want to notify them on the fly if they try to enter a username that's already in use. 
Since it's jinja2, I can pass the current list of used usernames to the frontend, but how do I then use those without using javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that without JavaScript on the client side. But, what you can do is pass the list as a JAvaScript array String to the client and put it into the javascript code to verify the input on the client. For example in a method called by textbox .onblur.